Can't rearrange files in Project Navigator
I created a new workspace. I added several files and folder to it. Now I can’t rearrange the files within the groups. Files in the Project Navigator are only showing up in strict alphabetical order in each group.
This problem is not showing up in other older workspaces.
The problem does show up in another new workspace I just created.
Does anyone know a setting in Xcode that could be causing this?
It could be a beta problem. I'm using Version 16.0 beta 4 (16A5211f). I have filed feedback with Apple.

yeah we should see.

It's been like this from the first 16.0 beta. I've looked through all settings and I can't find a fix. Hope they see your feedback.

I just downloaded and installed beta 5 and it's still a problem.

Right click on the project folder and select "Convert to Group"
Xcode 16 by default now creates a "Folder" for your project content instead of a "Group". Folders do not allow rearrangement and this is the behavior you are seeing. There are various other details and differences between Folders and Groups in Xcode.
Read this entry, and the response from apple in the Developer Forum.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/759620
I myself am also disappointed at the new default behavior, but the "Change to Group" workaround is quite simple.

Great solution. Thank you. One note, if you have nested folders you need to select the top folder for convert to group to work.

This is it, the right answer that is still valid. Thank you, sir!
